# How to use result from a query as attribute to select from input?

Tags: jq

given a input `{ "type": "dropdown"}`, I want to turn the type to `select`, based on the following type mapping, possible to do this in jq? Thanks

```
{
        "radiogroup": "radio",
        "checkbox": "checkbox",
        "dropdown": "select",
        "text": "text",
        "rating": "rate",
        "boolean": "switch",
        "comment": "textarea"
    }
```

PS: check  https://jqplay.org/s/BQo197AF7Q for demo of using the lookup table approach.

Comment: Please clarify the question by showing the expected result, and preferably by showing at least one of your attempts, which should clarify the source or sources of the two inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the lookup object to a variable first:

```
{ "radiogroup": "radio", "checkbox": "checkbox", "dropdown": "select", "text": "text", "rating": "rate", "boolean": "switch", "comment": "textarea" }
  as $lookup | $lookup[.type]
```

Answer (score 1):

If both the `input` and `map` objects are in separate files we can use an alternative to [Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69032847/5625547)'s solution, were we read both object into a single array using the `-s` (slurp) option.

---

Then we can

```
jq -s '.[1].type = .[0][.[1].type] | last' map input
```

- Change `.type` (on second index) to the mapped value from the first index
  `.[1].type = .[0][.[1].type]`
- Output only the second object
  `| last`

Which will produce

```json
{
  "type": "select"
}
```

---

Example from my local machine:

```
$ jq . map
{
  "radiogroup": "radio",
  "checkbox": "checkbox",
  "dropdown": "select",
  "text": "text",
  "rating": "rate",
  "boolean": "switch",
  "comment": "textarea"
}
$ jq . input
{
  "type": "dropdown"
}
$
$ jq -s '.[1].type = .[0][.[1].type] | last' map input
{
  "type": "select"
}
$
```